# Replication from log shipping database

Tags: sql-server, replication, log-shipping

I have a secondary database on a standby and read only mode.
The question is .. Can I replicate this database ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the same logs to maintain an additional secondary? Why would you want to add replication to this solution?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Granted this post is old, though one valid use case in OP's scenario would be if he was migrating a Publisher and Subscriber server part of the same replication topology, to newer servers and he wanted to have the old set of servers running concurrent to the new set while also keeping the new servers transactionally synchronized until verified that everything is working as expected on the new servers and fully cutting over. Not sure if that's OP's case, but unfortunately that's where I find myself as I stumbled on this post hoping I would be able to replicate the secondary lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However, there are some capabilities supported with log shipping and replication on the primary. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151224.aspx

As Aaron stated, you could add an additional secondary. If you wanted to use replication to handle subsets of the primary data, or build out a better formatted reporting server (different indexes, subsets of data through filtering, etc), then I would recommend replicating from the primary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanxs. But my real problem is with the secondary db in the log shipping.  The database use is for reports and analysis and every restore ALL of them are disconnected.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily recommend log shipping secondary as a reporting server. Transactional replication allows for the reporting server to have different indexing (which would be expected for reporting), and limit the data set maintained on the reporting server. There is a little more setup required with replication, but the flexibility offered far outweighs the setup cost.